# jQuery not finding inputs in table cells

Tags: jquery, html

I have a strange issue with my table cell value.

**My HTML is like:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> celll </td>
      <td> celll </td>
      <td> celll </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> celll </td>
      <td> <input type='text'> </td>
      <td> <input type='text'> </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to replace the cell that has `input` tag.

**So I:**

```
 $('table').find('td').each(function(){
      if($(this).text()==''){
          console.log('found input')  

      }
  })
```

However, I can't seem to find it with my codes.

Any tips here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.text()` method gets the combined text contents of each element and it would also returns all white spaces or new-lines.

So you could trim the string by using `$.trim` method:

```
$('table').find('td').each(function() {
  if($.trim($(this).text()) === ''){
    console.log('found input');  
  }
});
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/oFeN/1/edit)**

### Update

Another option would be using `.find()` method again as the example below, **BUT** according to my **[JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/grab-table-cell-value)**, using *jQuery 1.8.x*, this has a **lower** performance:

```
$('table').find('td').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('input').length){
    console.log('found input');  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).text()` will somehow 'remove' the html tags, but it will keep all the characters present as text in your nodes. This will include the white spaces.

With your example, the `.text()` call will return `" cell "` (space - "cell" - space) or `"  "` (space - space) - as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qZghd/1/).

Identifying a cell based on its sole `.text()` value is a poor choice indeed. Try [mithunsatheesh' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18411152/86072), or try to add some `id` or `class` attribute to your cell, and use the appropriate selector.

If you gave more context, maybe someone could give you a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the other's are right, the `text` is probably returning a few spaces.

You could make your life easier and use has.

```
$('td').has('input');
```

or if it's possible the other elements also have a input you could do this

```
$('td').has('input').filter(function(){
   return $(this).children() === 1;
});
```

Or if you wan't to stick to your `text` method you can trim the whitespace

```
$('td').each(function(){
   if( $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '') === '' ) {
      console.log('Input found!');
   }
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ck6zn/**